# Scanner - Matrix of char in Java

Tags: java, matrix, java.util.scanner

I just started learning this language and I have a problem trying to create a Matrix of type char from user input.

For example I want to read this as my input:

```
3 // this is an int n that will give me a square matrix[n][n]
.#.
###
.#.
```

For this example, this is what I have:

```
//...
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

int n = stdin.nextInt();
char[][] matrix = new char[n][n]

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
  matrix = stdin.nextLine();
}
```

Obviously this is wrong, and I know that. I'm just not seeing a way to correctly read this input.
If anyone could help me I would appreciate it.

ps: if possible, keep it simple, because like I said, I just started learning java :)

Comment: You can use `String.toCharArray()` to convert your Strings into `char[]`.

Comment: And you need to assign to matrix row, not the whole matrix.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add `stdin.nextLine();` after reading `n` to skip the new line character.

Second, this is what you need inside your loop:

```
matrix[i] = stdin.nextLine().toCharArray();
```

This reads next line and converts it to an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

This is a runnable version of your question with output

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainNoFXML extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        System.out.println("Enter Matrix Size:");
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = stdin.nextInt();
        char[][] matrix = new char[n][n];

        stdin.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter "+n+" Number of Chars");
            System.arraycopy(stdin.nextLine().toCharArray(), 0, matrix[i], 0, n);
        }

        System.out.println("\nYour Matrix:");
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[i]));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter Matrix Size:
3
Enter 3 Number of Chars
.#.
Enter 3 Number of Chars
###
Enter 3 Number of Chars
.#.

Your Matrix:
[., #, .]
[#, #, #]
[., #, .]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for all your answers.
I emailed my teacher and this was the solution he gave to me, if anyone is wondering:

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

int n = stdin.nextInt();
stdin.nextLine();

char[][] matrix = new char[n][n]

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
  String line = stdin.nextLine();
  for(int j = 0; i < n; j++){
    matrix[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
 }
}
```

Comment: in inner for loop, there should be j < n;

Answer (score -1):

see code sample:

```
public class MatInput {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int matX = 3; 
     int matY = 3;

     String matrix [][]=new String[matX ][matY];

             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("enter the strings for the Matrix");
              for(int row=0;row<matX;row++){
                 for(int col=0;col<matY;col++){
                     matrix[row][col]=input.nextLine();
             }
                 System.out.println("");
         }

              for(int r=0;r<matrix.length; r++) {
                  for (int c=0; c<matrix [r].length; c++) {
                      System.out.print(matrix [r][c] + "  ");
                  }          
                  System.out.println("");
              }

              input.close();
  }
}
```